# Ansible doesn't return correct group_vars, why?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

`deploy.yaml`

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: host_a
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        var: demo
```

`inventory`

```
[host_a]
localhost

[host_a:vars]
demo=aaa

[host_b]
localhost

[host_b:vars]
demo=bbb
```

When I run the playbook, I want the variable `demo` to return `aaa`, but it returns `bbb`.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

> Ansible doesn't return correct group_vars, why?

Because a variable defined in inventory is treated as a fact, and a fact is bound to a host in Ansible. As you define only one host, named `localhost`, the first value gets overwritten.

Confirm with:

```
[host_a]
127.0.0.1

[host_a:vars]
demo=aaa

[host_b]
127.0.0.2

[host_b:vars]
demo=bbb
```

or

```
[host_a]
localhost1 ansible_ssh_host=localhost

[host_a:vars]
demo=aaa

[host_b]
localhost2 ansible_ssh_host=localhost

[host_b:vars]
demo=bbb
```

Comment: Except change hosts, is there have other way?in my playbook, the hosts is set by group pattern, in my opinion the group_vars is used match by group